# psql: could not connect to server error on "travis-ci"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, travis-ci

My build is broken on travis-ci:

```
$ psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The command "psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres" failed and exited with 2 during.

I'm usin this `.travis.yml`:

Yaml Version updated on 05/31/2020:

```
dist: trusty

env:
    global:
      - PGPORT=5433

services:
    - postgresql

addons:
    postgresql: '10'
    apt:
        packages:
        - postgresql-10
        - postgresql-client-10

before_script:
    - export RUBYOPT='-W0' # to remove ruby 2.7 warnings
    - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml

language: ruby

rvm:
    - 2.7.0

script:
    - bundle exec rails db:reset db:setup db:migrate
    - bundle exec rspec
    - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml

before_install:
    - gem update --system
    - gem install bundler
```

Comment: have you installed Postgres server on your machine?

Comment: This is used on travis-ci, in my machine was ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED AFTER SOLUTION:**

I was able to find out what was wrong. See below the definitive solution:

**First:**  Travis wasn't compactive with postgres-10 (in the past)

**Second:** I needed remove the line that create a new database.

```
services:
    - postgresql

addons:
    postgresql: '9.6'

before_script:
    - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml

language: ruby

rvm:
    - 2.5.0

script:
    - bundle exec rails db:reset db:setup db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec
    - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml
```

Comment: See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#using-a-different-postgresql-version for how to use PostgreSQL 10:
  apt:
    packages:
    - postgresql-10
    - postgresql-client-10

Comment: can you mention which line you removed?

Comment: Hi guy, unfortunately, I no longer remember which line was removed, since I updated the original post with the version that worked. But, "I think" that the line was creating the database again in the before_script. If you still need help, send an example of how your travis.yml is doing right here to try to help you.

Answer (score 5):

you need to add **services: postgresql** to start the service. check here:

```
language: ruby
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database db_test;' -U postgres
rvm:
  - 2.5.0
services:
  - postgresql
  - memcached
  - redis-server
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
before_install:
  - gem update --system
```

Comment: Hi... thanks for your time. I was able to find out what was wrong. See below the definitive solution:

First:  Travis isn't compactive with postgres-10
Second: I needed remove the line that create a new database.

    services:
        - postgresql

    addons:
        postgresql: '9.6'

    before_script:
        - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml

    language: ruby

    rvm:
        - 2.5.0

    script:
        - bundle exec rails db:reset db:setup db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
        - bundle exec rspec
        - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml

Answer (score 0):

It seems over the years, Travis CI switched over to something that wasn't able to infer that PostgreSQL was a dependency from the Gemfile in Ruby or for a Rails project.

Others have noted the missing services in the Travis configuration. Here is the missing piece explicitly:

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

I was wondering why my old projects started failing recently as I updated dependencies, but even old one that worked would fail if run again in master. This was tricky!

Reference:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#postgresql